# SQL is there a way to select rows that not similar by same columns

Tags: sql, database, select

SQL is there a way to select rows that not similar by same columns.

I have this table  `City_Names` database name `DataPostalCode`

```
id |AR        |HB        |ENG
---+----------+----------+-----------
1  |valueAR   |valueHB   |valueENG
---+----------+----------+-----------
2  |TamraAR   |TamraHB   |TamraENG
---+----------+----------+-----------
3  |TamraAR   |Tamra2HB  |TamraENG
---+----------+----------+-----------
4  |KabulAR   |KabulHB   |KabulENG
---+----------+----------+-----------
6  |KabulAR   |KabulHB   |KabulENG
---+----------+----------+-----------
7  |KabulAR   |KabulHB   |KabulENG
---+----------+----------+-----------
8  |Azor      |Azor      |Azor      
---+----------+----------+-----------
9  |Azor      |Azor      |Azor      
---+----------+----------+-----------
...
```

*This data above is just a demo not the real data.*

See rows `id`  4 and 6 and 7 have similar values by AR+HB+ENG.

Rows `id` 8 and 9 are the same.

But row `id` 1 are single.

And There are rows  `id` 2 and 3 (what I'm looking for) are similar by AR+ENG but column HB not similar.

So I'm train to write sql code that select those rows no similar like that and the result should be.

```
id |AR        |HB        |ENG
---+----------+----------+-----------
2  |TamraAR   |TamraHB   |TamraENG
---+----------+----------+-----------
3  |TamraAR   |Tamra2HB  |TamraENG
---+----------+----------+-----------
```

What should I write?

```
SELECT id,AR,HB,ENG FROM  City_Names ....;
```

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `exists` for this:

```
select cn.*
from city_names cn
where exists (select 1
              from city_names cn2
              where cn2.ar = cn.ar and
                    cn2.eng = cn.eng and
                    cn2.hb <> cn.hb
             );
```

You can also reduce this to a single row, if you prefer.  The exact syntax depends on the database:

```
select cn.ar, cn.eng,
       list_agg(cn.id, ',') over (order by id) as ids,
       list_agg(cn.hb, ',') over (order by id) as hbs
from city_names cn
group by cn.ar, cn.eng
having min(cn.hb) <> max(cn.hb);
```

The specific function for aggregating strings depends on the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exists` :

```
select cn.*
from City_Names cn
where exists (select 1 
              from City_Names cnn 
              where cn.AR = cnn.AR and cn.ENG = cnn.ENG and cn.HB <> cnn.HB
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `LEFT JOIN` to obtain the result:

```
SELECT
    T2.*
FROM
    temp AS T1
    LEFT JOIN temp AS T2 ON T1.AR = T2.AR AND T1.ENG = T2.ENG AND T1.HB <> T2.HB
```

Result:

```
id  AR  HB  ENG
3   TamraAR Tamra2HB    TamraENG
2   TamraAR TamraHB TamraENG
```

Comment: I test it like this.
SELECT
    T2.*
FROM
    City_Names AS T1
    LEFT JOIN City_Names AS T2 ON T1.AR = T2.AR AND T1.ENG = T2.ENG AND T1.HB <> T2.HB.. 
but it's give me error

Comment: @Abrahemhajhle Hi can you try out this fiddle? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=54e32708866fcd7007f0340788df7443